# express mongoose router query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Am trying to return all item with store name ,using the conditional query method ,but the it return all items insteads ,i tried the maybe my logic is wrong

because what am trying to achieve it return all data that where store name is ,is say max mart

```
route('api/discount/?store=storename)
```

and

```
 router.route('/discount/:store')
  .get(function(req,res){
    Discount.find({store:req.params.store}, function(err, discount){
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(discount);
    });
})
```

so i called api/discount/store ,but this return all the data ,does not make any queries

schema model

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var DiscountSchema   = new Schema({
   store: String,
   location : String,
   discount : Number,

});

  module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', DiscountSchema);
```

Comment: Can you show us what your Discount schema looks like?

Comment: You need to use findOne instead of find

Comment: thanks for your suggestion ,but i need to retain items with store = something , the items mustly would be more than one.<br> updated to better explain my problem

Answer (score 1):

You made a wrong query. You have a route to `/discounts/:discount_id and you` query for `store:req.params.store`, and a req.params.store doesn't exists, just a discount_id